# When does Redux resolve a dispatch if my action creator return promise?

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-thunk

[This post](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/1676#issuecomment-215413478), Dan write a snippet to demonstrate async action.

I'm wondering how does `Redux` know my `store` is completely updated ?

Is there a chance that `fetchedUser` has not updated yet during executing `dispatch(getUser(userId)).then` ?

What will happen if I write 
`setTimeout(()=>{ dispatch({ type: 'GET_USER_SUCCESS', id,  response }) }, 5000)` in `fetchUser.then` ?

```
export function getUser(id) {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: 'GET_USER_REQUEST', id })

    // Perform the actual API call
    return fetchUser().then(
      response => {
        // Reducers may handle this to show the data and reset isFetching
        dispatch({ type: 'GET_USER_SUCCESS', id,  response })
      },
      error => { ... }
    )
  }
}



export function getUserAndTheirFirstPost(userId) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    return dispatch(getUser(userId)).then(() => {
      // Assuming this is where the fetched user got stored
      const fetchedUser = getState().usersById[userId]

      // Assuming it has a "postIDs" field:

      const firstPostID = fetchedUser.postIDs[0]

      return dispatch(getPost(firstPostID))
    })
  } 
}
```

Kindly guide me for this.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redux is a library that works in a reactive way, so it waits for actions to be dispatched to spread the state changes to all the connected functions.

If you set a 5 seconds timeout to dispatch an action, for Redux it's the same as if you wait 5 seconds in real life and then call `dispatch()`. It will just respond to that action by updating all the connected functions.

**Your question is more about promises.**

> Is there a chance that fetchedUser has not updated yet during
>   executing dispatch(getUser(userId)).then ?

No, because you're using `.then` after the getUser action, and that is making sure that the fetchUser promise was already resolved. What could happen is that the user was not found or something like that, but in that block you can make sure that the fetchUser call is already completed.

The flow would go like this:

1. Call getUser(userId)
2. Dispatch GET_USER_REQUEST
3. Call fetchUser()
4. Wait until fetchUser is completed.
5. Dispatch GET_USER_SUCCESS
6. Run `fetchedUser = getState().usersById[userId]`
7. And so on..

> What will happen if I write setTimeout(()=>{ dispatch({ type:
>   'GET_USER_SUCCESS', id,  response }) }, 5000) in fetchUser.then

In this case, it *could* run the fetchedUser assignment line without the state being updated, since I assume what sets the user is the `GET_USER_SUCCESS` action, right? So if the request takes less than 5 seconds to complete, it would run the assignment before updating the state with the user data.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you answer, but I'm still curious that `dispatch(getUser(userId))` actually return a  promise, so when does Redux resolve this promise ? Does Redux make sure the `store` is updated before resolve this promise?

Comment: @WilsonLiao `dispatch` doesn't care about that promise. It just passess value returned by `getUser(userId)(dispatch)`. It happens that this value is a promise but it doesn't matter for `redux`. From `redux` standpoint it's just some value to be passed.

Comment: @WilsonLiao if you had `redux-promise` and called `dispatch(somePromise)`, `redux` would wait for that promise to resolve to some action and then passed that action to the rootReducer to get a new state. But you don't have `redux-promise` and don't dispatch a promise but a function.

Comment: finally figure it out after reading redux source code. because `dispatch` function returns `action`, so `dispatch(getUser(userId))` is actually equal to `fetchUser().then`, so it definitely executed after `fetchUser().then`.

thank you